# Why can`t The ItemListener Change the variables

Tags: java, swing, awt

When I use the `ItemListener` to Listen if the `CheckBox` is selected.
If the `CheckBox` b1 is selected,the boolean Variables will be changed in the function `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0)`. When the Listener process this event of 
selecting `CheckBox` b1, the varibles "IsCorrect" will be changed(such as transform `false` to `true`). The variable is changed immediately in the function.If I use an output function, the `true` state will be shown on the Console. But when I use this variable outside the class `SingleSelect`, for example,When using the function `Check()`, the variable "IsCorrect" comes back to the statue `false` again as if the function `itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0)` has never used.

So why this phenomenon comes to me?
Thanks for all your help and expecting for the explanations and answers.
(Other codes are omitted by me, I just show the point codes).

```
class SingleSelect extends Box implements ItemListener
{
    private Checkbox b1;
    private boolean IsCorrect=false;`  

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
        if(b1.getState()==answer)
        {
            System.out.println("Yes!");
            System.out.println(b1.getState());
            IsCOrrect();
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
    }

    private void IsCOrrect()
    {
        IsCorrect=true;
    }

    public boolean Check()
    {
        System.out.println("b1"+b1.getState());
        if(b1.getState()==answer)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: make it static and define it outside of your class

Comment: Please add code where you are trying to get the value